# TypeError: useContext(...) is undefined

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to use a custom hook that bring me functions to handle my TODOS on my context, but it gives me an error

*Uncaught TypeError: useContext(...) is undefined*

*The above error occurred in the  component:*

Complete Error Image

[image: 1]

TodoProvider.jsx

```
import { useReducer } from 'react';
import { useTodos } from '../hooks/useTodos';
import { TodoContext, todoReducer } from './';

export const TodoProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const init = () => {
    return [];
  };

  const [todos, dispatchTodos] = useReducer(todoReducer, {}, init);

  const { handleNewTodo, handleToggleTodo } = useTodos();

  return (
    <TodoContext.Provider
      value={{ todos, dispatchTodos, handleNewTodo, handleToggleTodo }}
    >
      {children}
    </TodoContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

useTodos.js

```
import { useContext } from 'react';
import { TodoContext } from '../context';
import { types } from '../types/types';

export const useTodos = () => {
  const { dispatchTodos } = useContext(TodoContext);

  const handleNewTodo = todo => {
    const action = {
      type: types.add,
      payload: todo,
    };

    dispatchTodos(action);
  };

  const handleToggleTodo = id => {
    dispatchTodos({
      type: types.toggle,
      payload: id,
    });
  };

  return { handleNewTodo, handleToggleTodo };
};
```

Comment: Please don't post your code and errors as images. It's impossible to copy-paste from them.

Comment: Your error message says its at line 6 of `useTodos.js` &. your screenshot shows another component.

Answer (score 1):

The error traceback in your image says

```
`useContext(...)` is not defined  
  useTodos (useTodos.js:6)
```

Since you aren't showing your `useTodos.js` file, I must rely on my crystal ball to tell me that you've forgotten to

```
import {useContext} from 'react';
```

in `useTodos.js`, hence "not defined".

---

Here's an one-file example based on your code that [verifiably does work...](https://codesandbox.io/s/so73474711-yto0nv?file=/src/App.js)

```
import { useReducer, useContext, createContext } from "react";

function todoReducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "add":
      return [...state, { id: +new Date(), text: action.payload }];
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

const TodoContext = createContext([]);
const TodoProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [todos, dispatchTodos] = useReducer(todoReducer, null, () => []);
  return (
    <TodoContext.Provider value={{ todos, dispatchTodos }}>
      {children}
    </TodoContext.Provider>
  );
};

function useTodoActions() {
  const { dispatchTodos } = useContext(TodoContext);

  function handleNewTodo(todo) {
    dispatchTodos({
      type: "add",
      payload: todo
    });
  }

  function handleToggleTodo(id) {
    dispatchTodos({
      type: "toggle",
      payload: id
    });
  }

  return { handleNewTodo, handleToggleTodo };
}

function useTodos() {
  return useContext(TodoContext).todos;
}

function TodoApp() {
  const todos = useTodos();
  const { handleNewTodo } = useTodoActions();
  return (
    <div>
      {JSON.stringify(todos)}
      <hr />
      <button onClick={() => handleNewTodo((+new Date()).toString(36))}>
        Add todo
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <TodoProvider>
      <TodoApp />
    </TodoProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: Sorry, it's the first time that I'm using stack overflow. How can I put the code without an image?

Comment: There's a button for code blocks in the editor; just paste your code in there...

Comment: Is better like that?

Comment: Yes, that's better. If that really is the code you're running, then you might be trying to use a version of React that's too old.

Comment: I'm using react 18 :/

Comment: See my edit, please...